# Word for something obvious that you've never thought of?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

While folding laundry, I realized that if one sock in a pair was inside-out, the other usually would be as well. This thought was obvious after I had it, and also would have been obvious had someone asked me the question, but since it had never come up it was hidden to me. Is there a word for something that is obvious once you think about it, but unlikely to be thought about?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please provide an example sentence how you would use that word, are you looking for a noun, an adjective or even a phrase?

Comment: **Obscure**, perhaps.

Comment: *"Hiding in plain sight"* doesn't quite fit your socks observation, and neither does *"Not seeing the wood for the trees"* which usually refers to an observer being too involved in the matter. I doubt you'll find a single word answer, but it's a good question.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Not a single word, but a useful idiom.</sub>

**Be (right) under your nose** — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose)

> to be in a place that you can clearly see
>
> *"I spent all morning looking for the book, and it was right under my nose the whole time."*
> *"She shoved the letter under her boss's nose (= made certain he saw it)."*

See more examples on [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/under+nose).